# Digital format of piano / sheet music scores?

Tags: xml, music-notation, musicxml

Is there any accepted standards regarding how sheet music or piano scores are stored mathematically instead of as images or PDFs?

Everything thereof are digitally represented such as in an XML or something, so when one needs, he or she can easily manipulate the music itself instead of just editing a PostScript image.

Any such format existing and the license to use to carry music scores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [musicXML](http://www.musicxml.com/for-developers/).  It's the common format used by the major music notation software packages, like [Finale](http://www.finalemusic.com/) and [Sibelius](http://www.sibelius.com/products/sibelius/7/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

While MusicXML is parhaps the common standard and most flexible, it's also worth mentioning [ABC Notation](https://abcnotation.com/) and [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org/).  These (especially ABC) read more like English, and are more amenable to source control.  When I just want to do "a little bit of music", I tend to reach for ABC these days, like for just writing scales to practice on my sax.  ABC has been around for a very long time, is quite powerful, and has quite an ecosystem around it - JavaScript libraries, lots of Linux command line tools (convert to PDF, SVG, etc.)  If you happen to be into Irish folk music, ABC has an *enormous* collection online.